# Effect of rotation of earth on levitating objects

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, earth, coriolis-effect

If a [drone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_aerial_vehicle) is designed, such that it applies a constant force equal to it's weight ($mg$) on air, to maintain a constant elevation (say of 10 meters). What will happen when considerable time has passed, taking into account the earth's rotation?

By the FBD of the drone, it's downward force, $mg$, and upward force, $mg$, yields net $F=0$, it only has a constant velocity, it acquired when it was in contact with surface, due to rotation of the earth.

So, it should just start drifting away from earth's atmosphere. But it doesn't, why?

Take the assumption that $g$ doesn't change with respect to height, also any other suitable conditions to simplify things...

It will be easy for me to understand things if up to graduation level mathematics is used.

Comment: [Does the ground beneath a levitating object change due to the rotation of the earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100564/)

Comment: In: "FBD of the drone,..", what does "FBD" mean? "Free-body Diagram"?

Comment: @BrendanDarrer yes

Comment: The drone gets its uplift from the surrounding air  do you suppose the air will start to move?

Comment: @trula ofcourse the air will move down when blades of drone push it downwards to levitate. But that i do not consider is any important factor with respect to the question that can have any influence in any way on the  results.

Comment: If air does not move drone has to advance relativ to air?

Comment: @trula i didn't fully understand your remark but i think the air does move down as its being pushed down constantly by blades of drone and the reactionary force from which provides uplift to the drone. However the reason i consider for the drone to leave the atmosphere is, when the weight of done is balanced by this reactionary force all its left with is constant velocity in the right direction becoz of that eventually it might drift away from earth. It could be completely bogus but that' how i think of it.